# how to track different different url in my appliction while download from google store?

Tags: android

In my app different different url link on buttons while click on button open google play store with url app.after that while user download the app. how to know app download in user mobile.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a try catch to see if the package name exists

```
try {
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.package.address",PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
//launch play store
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.package.address"));
startActivity(intent);
}
```